# Cannot open .exe after pyinstaller convert

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Running my GUI application created in PyQt5 using any IDLE or the file.py is running perfectly, however, when I converted the .py to .exe using Pyinstaller
I get an error every time I try to run the .exe file for some reason a small command window pops with an error and immediately disappear I screenshot the error before it closes. Any Idea Thanks in advance

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChqEo.jpg).

I tried to execute different commands for pyinstaller but no luck.

```
<pyinstaller filename -F > 
<pyinstaller filename -onefile >
<pyinstaller filename >
```

It's an app over 900 lines and I cannot upload all of that but I think according to the error first lines.
The error occurs so here are the lines of code.
The problem is within importing modules I believe.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from datetime import datetime
import time
import os, sys  #importing system modules

class Ui_MyTrophiesWindow(object):
    class save_txt_file(QWidget): 
     def GetSaveFile(self):
            path = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"Save MyTrophies.txt here", "MyTrophies", "*.txt")
            working_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)[0:-13]
            file = open(str(working_path) + "Txtpath.dat", "w+")
            for i in path:
                file.write(str(i))
            file.close()
```

Comment: Try to use a virtualenv and update your pyqt with `pip install -U pyqt5`. Recent versions don't need additional work. If still doesn't work let me know.

Comment: I tried it now it says up-to-date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very common that sometimes PyInstaller won't recognize all Qt5 dependencies especially QT core DLLs. A simple way is to just locate that file on your current Python path and feed it with [`add-data`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) flag in PyInstaller. Also, I suggest you not to use `upx` with PyQt as it may corrupt some DLLs:

```
pyinstaller --noupx -F --add-data "<Python_path>/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/bin/Qt5Core.dll;./PyQt5/Qt/bin" script.py
```

To verify the answer suppose below example:

```
import traceback
import os
import sys


def func():
   from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
   from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


try:
   if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
      print(sys._MEIPASS)
   func()
   print("Import OK!")
except Exception:
   traceback.print_exc()

input()
```

After you run the executable you would see the path for Pyinstaller (something like `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90202`), go to this path and search for the `Qt5Core.dll` and check if it is there.

Comment: Are you getting the same error? Also check the DLL path and see if the file is there.

Comment: Same exact error .. and the files are all there I even uninstalled it now and installed it back didnt help

Comment: You should be good with my answer, but I added more explanation check it.

Comment: Thanks for your replies my friend .I solved it by copying all pyqt dll files inside the app folder and inside PyQt5 folder that was created by pyinstaller. However, when I run your code it says import ok didnt show me the path so I figured out that the app was reading the dll files from PyQt5 folder within my app folder that pyinstaller created. but thank you anyway for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I had look your error and according to me, I think you need to (re)install Qt5core.dll module and to add it in the site-package/PyQt5/**init**.py path. You can download the dll file here:

http://www.telecharger-dll.fr/dll-Qt5Core.dll.html

Good evening

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have all the items of that app in the correct folder. Let me put an example that happened to me days ago:

I had an app with a folder named "options" that had 3 files (2 icons for my buttons ui and a .ini file). When I created the pyinstaller version of my program I **assumed** that it would somehow copy those files and pack them inside the --onefile file or into the dist folder (if not --onefile command was used). Nope, it didn't. 
After scratching my head for hours, I just copied the options folder from my source files and pasted it next to my --onefile file (or inside the dist folder).

After that, my app works without issues. So... make sure it has all the files it needs in the correct folders.

Comment: Thanks for your reply my friend .I solved it by copying all pyqt dll files inside the app folder and inside PyQt5 folder that was created by pyinstaller